# Syntax error upon adding bootstrap datepicker to date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm trying to add bootstrap datepicker to date fields in a form but I get a syntax error on loading the view.

Installed bootstrap datepicker:

```
# In Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

# In app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
*= require bootstrap-datepicker3

# In app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
```

In a view page in a form I had the following line:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD' %>
```

To add the datepicker, the [documentation](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails#using-bootstrap-datepicker-rails) suggests using:

```
<input type="text" data-provide='datepicker' >
```

Therefore, I changed my line to:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, data-provide: 'datepicker', placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD' %>
```

I didn't change `date_field` to `text_field` since in the migration file it is included as a date_field.

On loading the page in development I get a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
... :date, data-provide: 'datepicker', placeholder: '...
...                     ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong `erb` key format `data-provide`. for solving this syntax problem, do this -

```
  <%= f.date_field :date, 'data-provide': 'datepicker', placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD' %>
```

Now, if you facing datepicker problem, do this -

```
  <%= f.date_field :date, placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD', class: 'datepicker' %>
```

and add js in application.js

```
jQuery(document).on('focus', 'input.datepicker', function() {
   opts =  {format: 'M dd, yyyy', autoclose: true, orientation: 'auto top'};
   jQuery(this).datepicker(opts);
   jQuery(".datepicker").css("z-index",10000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the page then indeed loads. However, if I click on the field no calender pops up (it still has the same behavior as before I installed datepicker).

Comment: Thanks Amit, I tried it without 'core' but that made no difference (also restarted the server).

Comment: @Nick.......check in your browser console that if there is any javascript errors ?

Comment: Pretty new to this, so I hope I do this correctly: In the Web Console of Firefox under .NET there are all sorts of GET requests for datepicker, where it gets js files. These don't generate any errors. Under the JS tab of the console there's nothing, it's empty. Also when I click on the field (the moment the calender should pop up) the JS tab remains empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83424/discussion-between-amit-suroliya-and-nick).